# What term is used to refer to quiz bowl players?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a special term for quiz bowl/knowledge bowl/trivia game-show competitors or people who otherwise spend their time remembering trivia for such competitions?

Answer (score 3):

<s>**Quizzer** may be used for a quiz bowl player, at least in some places. There are several examples in this Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Quizzing_Championship) and related articles. This usage appears to be very informal, as I could not find a reputable dictionary that contains this definition. *Quizzer* does not appear to be globally embraced by quiz bowl participants. Most of the references I found were in India or on Wikipedia, with very few in North America and the UK. In any case, *quizzer* is not applied to TV game shows.</s> **Quizzer** has a different usage in India -- see Yaitzme's comment.

**Player** is commonly used for quiz bowl competitors.

**Contestant** is commonly used for TV game show competitors.

Someone who is serious about trivia may informally be called a **trivia junkie**, whether or not they compete.

Comment: As a quizzer from India . ..

Comment: Actually, even in India, 'quizzer' usually does not refer to participants of quiz bowl/trivia-game-show (partly due to the paucity of such shows in India). More accurately, it refers to participants of Indian funda quizzes (which are more like pub quizzes).